# Can I use VSTO worksheet for Web application

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Hi as per my knowledge VSTO has to be a desktop application. However according to my requirement users who supposed to add the data are sitting in 8 different countries. Now I think desktop application cannot be done, as the local data base where the EXCEL data has to be stored cannot be accessible from 8 different countries.

How Can I use VSTO in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO can only be used with microsoft office apps, you cannot host it on web. One possible solution for you would be you expose webservice to store data to database wherever it is and your VSTO addin communicate with web service.

Comment: Thank you very much Brijesh, how ever I could not able to find an example for this, if you could share some examples or links, that will be grateful.

Comment: Its quite trivial, on button click even of ribbon just call windows service like you normally do in wcf or through simple web request. On how to gather data from worksheet these reference can be handy http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-Tools-Office-2007/dp/0321533216/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1324535927&sr=8-1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128771.aspx

Comment: Thanks Brijesh, so I think these 5 users are, even not in the local domain, they can access the local data base, through webservices

Comment: should be fine if you can expose your webservice on iternet not intranet,but if you go VSTO way you also need to think about factors like updating component, office version on users machine. If its just a simple data upload better you consider using spreadsheet tools available in market or upload file on server and use oledb/office automation to load data in DB

Comment: Thanks Brijesh for this detailed help!!